# Why struts version 2.3.4.1 and not 2.4?

Tags: api, struts2, version, versioning, compatibility

Having an argument with my team members on the api difference and versioning I was stucked when it came to struts with four periods i.e. 2.3.4.1 (a bit weird) . I want to know why it has not picked version 2.4 but 2.3.4.1 ?? Where does the api difference cam in?

Comment: well these are not major releases and just came with some minor bug fixes, all major releases which come with some added features and known improvements are alined to main numbers like 2.4 and 2.5 but the maintenance one are kept like 2.4.1 etc

Comment: Because the last stable release is 2.3.4.1, not 2.4. Source: http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: @Pigueiras : but It could have been 2.4 that's the question.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi What does this in-depth versioning mean. i.e. 2.3.4.1 is there any nomenclature for this defined?

Comment: @pKs Aah, ok, I understood it now

Comment: @pKs:see the link and details of `Thilo` and i believe it will be able to answer most of it. next major release is 2.4 and once major release is out other minor one and as well other bug fixed/patched will follow it like 2.4.1 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache has [guidelines on release numbering](http://commons.apache.org/releases/versioning.html):

> Minor Releases
>
> Minor releases signify enhancements to a component that do not necessitate a major release. Developers may perform a minor release if the release is at least external-interface-compatible with the previous release.
>
> Point Releases
>
> A point release typically involves simple bug fixes or optimizations that do not introduce new features. Developers may perform a point release if the release is at least interface-compatible with the previous release.

So unless there are new API additions (which I have not looked at) you would not bump up the minor version number.

2.4 would be a "minor release".

2.3.4 (the last point release) [only lists internal changes](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/version-notes-234.html).

2.3.4.1 is not even a "point release", more like a patch, which seems to match the release notes, which say "Struts 2.3.4.1 includes important security fixes."

Answer (score 2):

See this [compatibility table](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/struts.html) for all struts API versions. There is a minor [ABI break](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/compat_reports/struts/2.3.4_to_2.3.4.1/bin_compat_report.html#Medium_Risk_Problems) between 2.3.4 and 2.3.4.1 in the `org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper` class, but overall compatibility is still 99.9%.

[image]

[image]